# Downloading Python 2.5.4 (from official website) in order to install it

Tags: download, python

I was quite hesitant about whether I should post this question here on "StackOverflow" or on "SuperUser", but finally decided to post it here as Python is more a programming language rather than a piece of software.

I've been recently using Python 2.5.4 that is installed on my computer, but at the moment I am not at home (and won't be for about two weeks from now), so I need to install the same version of Python on another computer. This computer has Windows XP installed – just like the one that I have at home.

The reason why I need Python 2.5.4 is because I am using “Google App Engine”, and I was told that it only supports Python 2.5

However, when I went to the official Python page for the download, I discovered that certain things have changed, and I don’t quite remember where exactly from that site I had downloaded Python 2.5.4 on my computer at home.

I found this page: 
http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/

Here is how it looks:

[image]

A few things here are not clear to me.

It says:

---

> For x86 processors: python-2.5.4.msi
>
> For Win64-Itanium users:
>   python-2.5.4.ia64.msi
>
> For Win64-AMD64 users:
>   python-2.5.4.amd64.msi

---

First of all, I don’t know what processor I am using – whether mine is “x86” or not; and also, I don’t know whether I am an “Win64-Itanium” or an “Win64-AMD64” user. Are Itanium and 
AMD64 also processors?

Later it says:

---

> Windows XP and later already have
>   MSI; many older machines will already
>   have MSI installed.

---

I guess, it is my case, but then I am totally puzzled as to which link I should click as it seems now that I don’t need those three previous links (as MSI is already installed on Windows XP), but there is no fourth link provided for those who use “Windows XP” or older machines.
Of course, there are these words after that:

---

> Windows users may also be interested
>   in Mark Hammond's win32all package,
>   available from Sourceforge.

---

However it seems to me that it is something additional rather than the main file.

Where in the official Python website I can download Python 2.5.4, precisely, which link I should click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you will want to download will depend on the OS installed.

To find out if you are running x86 (32bit) or x64 (64bit), just goto Control Panel -> System and if it doesn't say you are running 64bit, then you are running 32bit.

See this for more info:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218

If you are running 32bit:
Download the x86 version, if you have 64bit download the Win64-AMD64 version.

Although, the other comments straight out say to download and install x86, there can be compatibility issues with running 32bit programs in a 64bit OS (I have seen them first hand). Would the Python interpreter be affected? Couldn't say for sure, but I am sure the 64bit version is certainly optimized to run on 64bit systems. So, I would advise you download the needed version.

Comment: Thank You, Nathan. I just tried Your way and both of those in Your link - they all show that my computer here is running 32-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Nathan, please, edit Your answer a bit, I think I accidentally clicked on the up-vote twice and, thus, discarded my up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

The first one will always work.

Comment: 32bit applications will not always work perfectly in a 64bit OS. Would python? Possibly, but that is not a chance I would want to take. In fact some 32bit applications won't install in a 64bit OS.

Comment: Most applications will both install and work, also it's much more likely that a XP install is 32 bit and not 64, therefor the tip to get the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You want the 32 bit one for x86 processors, the first one listed.

AMD64 is the 64 bit compilation for 64 bit x86 processors, but most people use the 32 bit version even if they are running a 64 bit OS.  Since pointers are 8 bytes wide your data cache performance suffers if you use the 64 bit version.  Unless you need to access more than 2 GB of memory from your Python app (or use a module that requires this), 64 bits won't do anything for you.

The Itanium is a 64 bit processor from Intel that was supposed to be our move to 64 bits, but AMD beat them to the punch and gave us the more backwards compatible AMD64 architecture (which Intel now refers to as x86-64, or x64).  I doubt most of us even know anyone who uses an Itanium.